# IE11 axios data response problem (random string included)

Tags: javascript, axios, internet-explorer-11

having problem with IE11 axios requests.
so i was testing axios connections on IE11

some random string is being included on response.data

some APIs are doing just fine but several having same problem

how can i fix this @.@

```html
index.html

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/promise-polyfill/8.2.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const test = axios.create({
    baseURL: window.location.origin,
    withCredentials: true,
    timeout: 100000
  })

  test.get("/dashboard")
    .then(function(e){console.log(e)})
    .catch(function(e){console.log(e)})
</script>
```

result

```json
response.data 

1e1a <--this is
{
"inUseSolutions":{"trialSolutionList"....
}
---------- other
4f9 <----what is this
[
{"solutionKey":...}
]
```

Comment: Hi songgunho, I simply tested it, and it did not show the problem. Have you tested it in other browsers and whether it has similar problems? And you mentioned that only part of the api will have a problem with the problem. I think this may be related to the api. You can try to check them.

Comment: thanks i just found out that there is some problem with webpack proxy table. i fixed it by excluding proxy change but still not sure about it. it worked just find in build files @.@